# use_doorkeeper causes problems when used within a scope route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, doorkeeper

I'm upgrading doorkeeper to 6.7 and I have a problem with use_doorkeeper:

I followed the [migration instructions](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Migration-from-old-versions) and did the following:

**my routes before the upgrade:**

```
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /.{2}/ do
    ...
    mount Doorkeeper::Engine => '/oauth', as: 'doorkeeper'
    ...
  end
```

**my routes after the upgrade:**

```
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /.{2}/ do
    ...
    use_doorkeeper
    ...
  end
```

**Now I get an error from this line (and others) in my view:**

```
<td><%= link_to application.name, [:oauth, application] %></td>
```

Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"doorkeeper/applications", :locale=>#< Doorkeeper::Application id: 5, name: "My App", uid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...", secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...", redirect_uri: "http://www.myapp.com", created_at: "2013-08-26 14:33:38", updated_at: "2013-08-26 14:33:38">}

It seems that doorkeeper application is getting into the locale param.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've followed the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params), you'll have something like the following in your `ApplicationController`.

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

But your doorkeeper controllers don't inherit from your `ApplicationController`. So if I were you I'd pull that out into a concern

```
module LocaleConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_locale
  end

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end

end
```

Then you can `include` this in your own `ApplicationController` in the normal way. For adding it to doorkeeper, there's a lot of options, but one thing you could do is add the following to config/application.rb

```
config.to_prepare do
  Doorkeeper::ApplicationController.send :include, LocaleConcern
end
```

Comment: You're right. The way we handle locale is according to the rails guide, so we already have set the `default url options` and `set locale`. The problem still happens.

Comment: Actually wait, I think I see why... updating answer